# Xtend operator overloading on existing class

Tags: java, operator-overloading, xtend

I tried to overload an existing external class's operator with Xtend but it doesn't work. I can't write in the class source, like BigIntegerExtension. How should I do it?

**Answer**

The answer is pretty simple. We can override any of the operators what we want with [operator overload](https://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation.html#operators).

```
// IntVar = IntVar
def static operator_equals(IntVar a, IntVar b) {
    return IntConstraintFactory.arithm(a, "=", b)
}
```

Comment: By `Xtend`, did you mean `extend`?

Comment: @RohitJain http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/

Comment: Yes I meant [link](http://eclipse.org/xtend)  Thanks @RohitJain.

Comment: You should move your answer to a real answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. We can override any of the operators what we want with operator overload.

```
// IntVar = IntVar
def static operator_equals(IntVar a, IntVar b) {
    return IntConstraintFactory.arithm(a, "=", b)
}
```

Comment: Hey :) I also found this helpful blog post http://mnmlst-dvlpr.blogspot.de/2014/10/xtend-operator-overloading.html

Comment: @kon It is a dead link